# Where can I see the size of a video on the YouTube application?

Tags: ios, ipad, youtube

I use YouTube premium to watch videos offline on my iPad (iPadOS 13). Where can I see the size of a video on the YouTube application?

I don't see any details when going to General -> Storage -> YouTube

[image]

---

[Joost C](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/265989/joost-c) suggested

> Enable "stats for nerds" in account (icon) > settings > toggle "stats for nerds". Then when playing a video, tap "more", select "stats for nerds".

However, stats for nerds don't show the video size:

```
{
    CPN = fSxRxnoQJUzknZJ7;
    date = "2021-03-21 00:03:45 +0000";
    debugParameters =     {
        ad = none;
        adcpn = "";
        audioitag = 140;
        connectiontype = 3;
        errorscreen = no;
        isdrm = no;
        ishls = no;
        islocal = yes;
        ismonetized = no;
        ismuted = no;
        mlplayer =         {
            docid = "vAC-x75akYI";
            rate = 1;
            type = "hamplayer_queue";
        };
        mobilecarrier = "";
        playertype = 15;
        qoeerrorcode = "";
        qoeerrordetails = "";
        resolution = 720p;
        state = 6;
        videoitag = 136;
        xtags = "";
    };
    videoID = "vAC-x75akYI";
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it depend on the bitrate ? [Youtube 720p video has more MB than 1080p](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/12487/youtube-720p-video-has-more-mb-than-1080p) So if youtube doesn't provide the data, you'd need average bitrate [What is the size of 1 minute video at 1920 x 1080 (60 fps)?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/15368/what-is-the-size-of-1-minute-video-at-1920-x-1080-60-fps)

Comment: @ankii yes but I'm assuming YouTube video encoding doesn't use constant bitrate. Also I don't know which encoding the YouTube iOS application is using when downloading videos.

Answer (score 1):

You can find them after you've enabled "stats for nerds" in account (icon) > settings > toggle "stats for nerds".

Then when playing a video, tap "more", select "stats for nerds".

Apparently we are nerds.

Comment: Thanks, stats for nerds don't show the video size (see the edited question).